# Control flow after ContextMenuStrip of vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vb6, contextmenu, popupmenu, control-flow

We are converting vb6 project to vb.net. In vb6 We used PopupMenu but in vb.net we couldn’t find PopupMenu. So we are planning to use its equivalent ContextMenuStrip.

In vb6 after showing PopupMenu with code "PopupMenu MenuName", control will not come to next line untill menu is clicked or escape key is pressed. Accordingly we have done many code after showing popup menu, which will get executed only after menu click.But in vb.net after showing ContextMenu immediately control will come to next line i.e. even before menu is clicked.

If we convert from vb6 to vb.net, codes which are written after popupmenu line have to be shifted. It will be big work. Is there any idea to make conversion process easier?

Comment: PopupMenu is modal, you'll have to create a Form that you display with ShowDialog() to get an equivalent.  Or move the code that is now after the PopupMenu call into the Click event handler(s) for the menu items.

Comment: If i show another modal form to get popup menu equivalent then along with popup menu form also displayed.

Comment: Make the form only as big as needed to contain the menu items.  Without a caption.  There is no real distinction between the windows used by Form and ContextMenuStrip, just different defaults.

Comment: I used ContextMenu instead of ContextMenuStrip and now all works perfectly.